# How to embed vimeo player in react-native without webview?

Tags: react-native, vimeo

I need a vimeo player for my react-native app, but it can't be an WebView. There are some apps with this behaviour, but I can't find libs for it.

```
const html = `<iframe ... src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/${video.id}"></iframe>` 
<WebView ... source={{ html  }} />
```

This snippet is my current player, but it doesn't offer a good user experience for being webview.

Comment: have you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this module. `React Native Vimeo Player`

You can run `npm install react-native-vimeo`

**Usage**

```js
<Vimeo
    ref='video'
    videoId='2619976' // Vimeo video ID
    onReady={ () => console.log('Video is ready') }
    onPlay={ () => console.log('Video is playing') }
    onPlayProgress={ data => console.log('Video progress data:', data) }
    onFinish={ () => console.log('Video is finished') }
  />
```

Comment: Internally, that library is using a WebView